# VS2005 disable inline

Tags: c, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to get inline functions represented in a map file. Currently map file does not have inline function symbols as they are getting expanded.

So, I have tried to use /Ob0 compilation option to disable it. But I still can not see them reflected in a map file. Am I doing something wrong.

Thanks,

My environment is VS2005

Comment: Try to disable *all* optimizations. The compiler will often decide to inline functions even when not declared explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this possibly a side effect of `inline` allowing the function to have a definition in multiple translation units - maybe this is part of how VS gets around that?

You could possibly test this by using the preprocessor (`#define inline` or whatever) although if it is the case it doesn't seem possible to solve easily since defining that globally would cause the functions to be multiply-defined.